# Can't show error message after failed spring mvc form validation

Tags: java, jpa, spring-mvc, validation, bean-validation

I have class in business model :

```
public class User {
     @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Username must be between 3 and 20 characters long")
     @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", message = "Username must be alphanumeric with no spaces")
     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     @Column(name = "user_id")
     private Long userID;

     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinTable(name = "userDic", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
 @JoinColumn(name = "acc_id", referencedColumnName = "acc_id") })
     @LazyCollection(value = LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
     private Set<Account> allAccounts; //............. //constructors , setters , getters here
```

In jsp input of new User happens via spring form :

```
<form:form method="post" action="AddUser" modelAttribute="user">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name">First Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="*" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Add User" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

Here is controller that handle this jsp :

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class AdminServlet
{

    /* private UserValidator validator;

     @InitBinder("user")
     protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
     {
         binder.setValidator(validator);
     }*/

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView showUsers() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("index");
        mav.addObject("ATMUsers", MainService.getAllUsers());
        mav.addObject("user", new User());
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/AddUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String AddUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result)
    {
        if (!result.hasErrors())
            MainService.AddUser(user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

Validation happens correctly for field `name`. But controller just reload the page and I don't see any kind of error message.

If I uncomment code in controller about `UserValidator` and `InitBinder` I will get error but it is not text within  `<form:errors path="*" />` , but java exception

> javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: validation failed for classes [com.antonbanking.business.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]

The question is what I did wrong to just get validation error message ? BTW [full code is available in github](https://github.com/asmorodskiy/AntonBanking/tree/second).

Comment: Can you give us a more detailed stack trace?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25516021/StackTrace.txt -  stack trace for case when IntinBinder part is uncommented

Answer (score 4):

I solve problem by myself - issue was in return of AdminServlet.AddUser . because I made `"redirect:/"` this cause creating of brand new objects including BindingResult so all info about error was erased.
After change

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/AddUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String AddUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result)
    {
        if (!result.hasErrors())
            MainService.AddUser(user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

to

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/AddUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView AddUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result)
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("index");
        mav.addObject("ATMUsers", MainService.getAllUsers());
        if (result.hasErrors())
            mav.addObject("user", user);
        else
        {
            mav.addObject("user", new User());
            MainService.AddUser(user);
        }
        return mav;
    }
```

All starts working correct .

Answer (score 0):

Catch exception around `MainService.AddUser(user);` and in catch clause add errors to BindingResult object or redirect.

See [BindingResult (addError or reject* from Errors)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html)
See also [Validation (without annotation)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion this force me to catch ConstraintViolationException in two places :
1. Hibernate level - where actually exception happens to close opened session (because it is not HibernateException it fails to be catched)

2. After I rethrow it and catch again in `MainService.AddUser(user)` 
But after all I still get exception - now another one - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25516021/Error2.txt.

Generally I don't think that this is good way - Catching same exception in two places .

Comment: Also in links that you give (BTW I already read this one -  Validation (without annotation))  I din't find any examples when need to catch  ConstraintViolationException ...

Comment: Instead of catching and rethrowing the exception, you can just catch unchecked exception (that extends RuntimeException) from your controller...

Comment: The reason why I catch and rethrow is because first time I catch to rollback and correctly close transaction (Hibernate ) and second to add error to BindingResult (Controller level).
If I will catch error only in controller than I will get exception about not closed session (Hibernate session)

Comment: `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.antonbanking.business.User entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)` - this is what I get if I catch only in controller